# Set interlacing information in QuickTime

Tags: quicktime

I'm trying to set the correct interlacing information via the QuickTime 7 API on a movie that I am creating.

I want to make my movie progressive scan but when I visually check the output, every frame is squashed into the top half. So even though I make sure QuickTime knows my movie is `kQTFieldsProgressiveScan` it still gets confused.

This is what I am doing:

```
myCreateNewMovie(...);
ICMCompressionSessionOptionsCreate(...);
BeginMediaEdits(media);

myCreate(ImageDescription with appropriate FieldInfoImageDescriptionExtension2);
SetMediaSampleDescription(media, ImageDescription);
```

and then when writing each frame I add the same description:

```
ICMImageDescriptionSetProperty(myFieldInfoImageDescription, ...);
AddMediaSample2(...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From various bits and pieces on the net I got the impression that setting the sample description for the media was getting overwritten. Now I'm setting the `FieldInfo` data inside my ICM Encoded Frame Output callback and it seems to be satisfactory.